# database won't connect to my discord bot on digitalocean (discord.py)

Tags: mysql, discord.py, digital-ocean

I use digitalocean and added database management to my droplets and made all possible options but it can't connect ... I tried putting `sslmode="REQUIRED"` but it gives me another error where it says I shouldn't put it ... like do I get the database to connect to my discord bot? (the droplets is ubuntu)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peppe/.venvs/discord/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 232, in _open_connection
    self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'discordbotdatabase....com:3306' (4)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LMIIBotDevelopment.py", line 29, in <module>
    lmiibot_db = mysql.connector.connect(
  File "/home/peppe/.venvs/discord/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 272, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/peppe/.venvs/discord/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 85, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/home/peppe/.venvs/discord/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1003, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/home/peppe/.venvs/discord/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 232, in _open_connection
    self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

```py
import mysql.connector

lmiibot_db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="discordbotdatabase....com",
    user="doadmin",
    passwd="password",
    database="lmiibot",
    auth_plugin="mysql_native_password",
)
```

Comment: that a server is acceible directly from the internet is not normal, see if you don't use localhost

Comment: i am not using localhost at the moment. i added the code inside my ubuntu droplets ... i didn't find any tutorials so i tried to do so. [image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/681892318915330084/841068181593784351/unknown.png)

Comment: i don't know your hoster but a diect access from the Internet is dangerous and **not** recomended, that is why itis usually not explained and you get told to use a REST API on the server in qzestion

Comment: unfortunately I know little about servers in general, I don't know how to do it I would just like to have available for things with the bot.

Comment: security and more is a vital today that very ip gets scannned every millisecond. You must take the time to learn, maybe some else has a good starting point.

Comment: do you have any suitable links for what i do? (discord bot)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232159/discussion-between-peppewarrior1-and-nbk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I forgot to add the server port

```py
import mysql.connector

lmiibot_db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="discordbotdatabase....com",
    port="port"
    user="doadmin",
    passwd="password",
    database="lmiibot",
    auth_plugin="mysql_native_password",
)
```